# Updating Rails 4 Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm having a hard time with Rails and nested attributes and would really appreciate some help.

Here is the output from my console session where I was attempting to get the updated values to save but as you can see, they don't seem to take on the next line when I perform the find again:

```
irb(main):070:0* e = Equipment.find(26)
  Equipment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "equipment".* FROM "equipment" WHERE "equipment"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 26]]
=> #<Equipment id: 26, name: "fdsfsdsdfsd2", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:43", updated_at: "2015-11-02 16:38:55", site_id: 57, type_id: 3>
irb(main):071:0> e.update({"name"=>"fdsfsdsdfsd2", "site_id"=>"57", "type_id"=>"3", "equipment_properties_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"15", "value"=>"2015-10-34", "property_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"16", "value"=>"fsdfdsfsd", "property_id"=>"5"}}})
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  EquipmentProperty Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "equipment_properties".* FROM "equipment_properties" WHERE "equipment_properties"."equipment_id" = $1 AND "equipment_properties"."id" IN (15, 16)  [["equipment_id", 26]]
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):072:0> e.equipment_properties
  EquipmentProperty Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "equipment_properties".* FROM "equipment_properties" WHERE "equipment_properties"."equipment_id" = $1  [["equipment_id", 26]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<EquipmentProperty id: 15, equipment_id: 26, property_id: 4, value: "2015-10-34", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51", updated_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51">, #<EquipmentProperty id: 16, equipment_id: 26, property_id: 5, value: "fsdfdsfsd", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51", updated_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51">]>
irb(main):073:0> e = Equipment.find(26)
  Equipment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "equipment".* FROM "equipment" WHERE "equipment"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 26]]
=> #<Equipment id: 26, name: "fdsfsdsdfsd2", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:43", updated_at: "2015-11-02 16:38:55", site_id: 57, type_id: 3>
irb(main):074:0> e.equipment_properties
  EquipmentProperty Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "equipment_properties".* FROM "equipment_properties" WHERE "equipment_properties"."equipment_id" = $1  [["equipment_id", 26]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<EquipmentProperty id: 15, equipment_id: 26, property_id: 4, value: "2015-10-30", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51", updated_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51">, #<EquipmentProperty id: 16, equipment_id: 26, property_id: 5, value: "fsdfdsfsd", created_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51", updated_at: "2015-11-02 15:26:51">]>
```

The same thing is happening with the web interface.  I can provide additional details if anyone needs them but I am allowing the parameters through and on creation, the initial values are saved.

I've been beating my head against this all morning and I suspect it is something stupid but I'm just not sure what to try next. Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
Equipment Model:

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :properties
  has_many :equipment_properties

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :equipment_properties, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And also the equipment_properties model:

```
class EquipmentProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :equipment
  belongs_to :property
  has_one :type, through: :equipment

end
```

Also, of relevance might be that I can update the individual equipment_property  without nesting and that does work.

UPDATE 2:

I managed to add this to the controller and it saves the values now.  Not pretty but it works I guess...

```
equipment_params[:equipment_properties_attributes].each do |property|
      ep = EquipmentProperty.where(id: property[1][:id]).first
      #logger.debug "EP Value: #{ep.value}"
      #logger.debug "Property Value: #{property[1][:value]}"
      ep.value = property[1][:value]
      ep.save
    end
```

Comment: What does the relevant part of your `Equipment` model look like? Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :equipment_properties`?

Comment: That's a valid question.  I do have it in there: accepts_nested_attributes_for :equipment_properties, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

Comment: Are they added in the required params for strong params in yer controller?
params.require(:equipment).permit(:yer_attributes, yer_nested_attributes: [:id, :name, :etc])

Comment: Also, a good question.  They are allowed and I've even tried being permissive and allowing all parameters: params.require(:equipment).permit(:id, :name, :site_id, :type_id, equipment_properties_attributes: [:id, :value, :property_id, :equipment_id])

Comment: The controller params wouldn't matter in this instance

Comment: Can you try it again but call a different variable name. You're using `e` twice, it might be saving the associative data or something. It would be better if you tried with a different variable name.

Comment: Using e twice shouldn't matter but I did try it with a second variable and results were the same.  I ran the following: e = Equipment.find(26)
e.update({"name"=>"fdsfsdsdfsd2", "site_id"=>"57", "type_id"=>"3", "equipment_properties_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"15", "value"=>"2015-10-34", "property_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"16", "value"=>"fsdfdsfsd", "property_id"=>"5"}}})
e.equipment_properties
f = Equipment.find(26)
f.equipment_properties

Comment: In the console, try:
res = e.update(blah blah..)
res
This will catch the return value.  Make sure it is true.  If not, try 
e.valid? 
e.errors
to see what errors exist.

Comment: Alternatively, use update! instead of update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up adding to the controller to resolve this.  Definitely a hack though and I'm not sure why the updates are taking:

```
equipment_params[:equipment_properties_attributes].each do |property|
      ep = EquipmentProperty.where(id: property[1][:id]).first
      #logger.debug "EP Value: #{ep.value}"
      #logger.debug "Property Value: #{property[1][:value]}"
      ep.value = property[1][:value]
      ep.save
end
```